# Отправка команд на сетевой принтер esc / pos

Tags: принтер

Подскажите пожалуйта. Есть чековый принтер Xprinter q260. Как я могу отправить ему команды esc/pos через url? Принтер подключен к Ethernet. При переключении на `http://192.168.0.110:9100` принтер печатает информацию об устройстве, с которого перешли по веб-ссылке.

Comment: Через урл, вероятно, никак, т.к. там фактически raw access, никакого HTTP. Это и не веб-ссылка, в общем-то. Но если вы туда прицепитесь телнетом и будете выдавать данные, то они должны быть переданы принтеру в неизменном виде, а принтер уже будет интерпретировать escape sequences самостоятельно.